# Group data lines when iterating

Tags: c#, iterator

I am developing an application for parsing a data file. Since it is big file, it is not appropriate to load into memory. So I iterate the data file. But the data file is structured like

```
1. master data line1
2. master data line2
3. detail data line2-1
4. detail data line2-2
5. master data line3
6. master data line4
7. detail data line4-1
8. detail data line4-2
9. detail data line4-3
10.  ......
```

I need to group related data lines together, then send one transaction to database. Does anybody have similar issue before? Any better way?

Thanks,

Comment: Is it always the case that the detail lines immediately follow the master lines?

Comment: group the into what? what are you doing with the data?

Comment: It looks like your related data lines (master, detail1,detail2, etc) are already grouped together.

Comment: You could make it a csv file and store the file in a temporary sql table and then run a group by on it.

Answer (score 0):

Peek into the next line; if it is master proceed as usual, if it is detail append the line and peek into the next line.

Comment: Yes, it is my question, how to peek the next line during iterating.

Comment: Could you give more detail into what classes are you currently using to read through the data files? A code snippet would be useful...

Answer (score 0):

Use the following the process a bunch of related records together in a group. It also does not load entire file in memory at once.

```
List<string> collection = new List<string>();

foreach( var line in File.ReadLines("file.txt") )
{
     if( line.StartsWith("master"))
     {
        if( collection.Count > 0 )
        {
             WriteRecords(collection);
        }
        collection.Clear();
     }
     collection.Add(line);
}
```